# Appending selected checkboxes to another div

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to write a function that moves any selected checkboxes from one div to another, however currently only the id of the selected checkboxes are being appending to the "Added" div. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

```
 <fieldset>
    <h3>Pages</h3>
        <div class="fieldset_elements">
            <div id="pagecontainer">
                <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox1">
                    <h4>Available Pages</h4>
                        {foreach from=$pagelist item=page}
                             <div class="pageSelection"><input type="checkbox" id="{$page.id}" class="pages" value="{$page.id}">{$page.page_name}</div>
                        {/foreach}
                </div>
                <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox2">
                    <h4>Selected Pages</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

$(function(ready) {
    $(".pages").change(function () {
        var pageId = $(this).attr('id');
        if(pageId.checked = true){
            $("#pagebox2").append(pageId);
        } else if(pageId.checked != true) {
            $("#pagebox1").append(pageId);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the changed checkbox's id attribute. this attribute can't be checked or unchecked.

What you are probably looking for is the `checked` prop of the element:

```
var page = $(this);
var checked = page.prop('checked');
```

finally what you want to add to one of the "pagebox" is not the checkbox itself but the checkbox container: `page.parent()`.

Here is the solution:

```
$(function(ready) {
    $(".pages").change(function () {
        var page = $(this);
        var checked = page.prop('checked');

        if(checked){
            $("#pagebox2").append(page.parent());
        } else {
            $("#pagebox1").append(page.parent());
        }
    });
});
```

Some changes to the markup too (the input tag is self closing):

```
<fieldset>
<h3>Pages</h3>
    <div class="fieldset_elements">
        <div id="pagecontainer">
            <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox1">
                <h4>Available Pages</h4>
                    {foreach from=$pagelist item=page}
                         <div class="pageSelection"><input type="checkbox" id="{$page.id}" class="pages" value="{$page.id}">{$page.page_name}</div>
                    {/foreach}
            </div>
            <div class="selectpagebox" id="pagebox2">
                <h4>Selected Pages</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5L9c6fp4/)

Comment: Thank you for this solution!